# How to load all the data at once when select multiple check boxes - Jquery AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have `AJAX` load country city list as below screen shot. When continent is checked it will load it countries from the database.

[image]

Here when checked another continent it will load that related countries. But I want to keep both country list and show all countries.

My current js code is

```
$("#continent input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
                     if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        var checked = $(this).val();
                        var type = 'country';
                        //alert(checked);
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: '<?php echo JURI::root(); ?>index.php?option=com_ajaxwork',
                            data: {country : checked, type :type},
                            beforeSend: function() {
                                $('#countries').html("<img src='/images/loading.gif' />");
                            },
                            success: function(e) {
                                $('#countries').html(e);
                            },
                            error: function() {
                                alert('it broke');
                            },
                            complete: function() {
                             //   alert('it completed');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    });
```

And `php` code is

```
    $countinent_id = $_POST['country'];
   $query2 = "SELECT * FROM #__my_country WHERE continent_id = $countinent_id"; 
   $db2 =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $db2->setQuery($query2);        
    $rows2 = $db2->loadObjectList();

    foreach ($rows2 as $value) {  
        print('
            <fieldset class="loc_field">
        <label>'.$value->country_name .'</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="jform[supplier_country_covered]['.$value->country_id.']" value="'.$value->country_id.'">
            </fieldset>
                ');
    }
```

How do I load all countries at once when checked multiple check boxes at first column.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try adding continent id as a class to fieldset in your php code. 
Then change your jQuery code to

```
$("#continent input[type='checkbox']").click(function () {
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var checked = $(this).val();
    var type = 'country';
    //alert(checked);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<?php echo JURI::root(); ?>index.php?option=com_ajaxwork',
        data: { country: checked, type: type },
        beforeSend: function () {
         //you have to show this some other way
         //   $('#countries').html("<img src='/images/loading.gif' />");
        },
        success: function (e) {
            $('#countries').append(e);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('it broke');
        },
        complete: function () {
            //   alert('it completed');
        }
    });
}
else {
    var checked = $(this).val();
    $('.' + checked).remove();
}
```

});

Comment: Thanks. But this is not work! Because `else` part is not reading here. I think you may have understood the issue incorrectly. Actually  I want load all corresponding countries when I check multiple selection from first column. currently It will show last check check box data

Comment: Else part is when you have to remove the countries of a continent and I have changed your .html() tag to .append(). I think that should work.

Comment: Did you get any error? It should work like it was a simple thing. Just don't clear the html of 'countries' section and simply append the ajax result.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there any method or way to get previously checked countries. Actually I want display non those countries when checked new checkbox from first column.

Comment: When a country is checked, You can add its id to a javascript array and use this array to check if this country have been selected previously.